# Android Studio 1.5 HTTP Proxy Timeout

Tags: http, android-studio, gradle, proxy

I upgraded to the latest version **Android Studio 1.5**.

I entered the settings of the proxy, from the menu, AND which gradle.properties.
But always receive timeout when I try to build.
If imposed "`work offline`", I get:

```
Error: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3 available for offline mode. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project.
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) then type "Work offline" to search bar. You can disable from screen.

Good luck

Comment: Then you shoud have problem with proxy. Can you test connection from Proxy from the Settings screen.

Comment: Can you open standalone SDK manager and check the settings for proxy?